# Homology of a higher-dimensional full torus with a certain disk removed

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $X=S^2\times B^5$ and let us consider an embedding of an
open $5$-disk in $X$ with its boundary
glued by a map of degree $2$ to some $\{
s_0\} \times S^{4}\subseteq \partial X$ . The embedding fits
into a neighborhood of $\{s_0\}\times B^5$ which can be parameterized
by $[-1,1]^2\times B^5$ and is defined as follows. We parameterize
the first two coordinates of the $5$-disks by polar
coordinate system, that is, every point of the $5$-disk is given
as a tuple $(r,\alpha,x_1,x_2,x_3)$. This point is embedded to
a point $(r(1-r)\sin\alpha, r(1-r) \cos\alpha, r,2\alpha,x_1,x_2,x_3)$.
Let $B$ denote the image of this embedding.

The question is as follows: what is the image of the map $H_2\big(X\setminus(\partial
X\cup B);\mathbf Z_2\big)\to
H_{2}\big(X;\mathbf Z_2\big)$ induced by the inclusion.

Comment: Did you try Poincar\'e--Lefschetz duality?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev I have no clue how whether the smaller space can be viewed as a manofild (with a boundary) and whether the Poincare or Lefschets duality could be used.

Comment: The map you are interested in is dual to $H^5(X,\partial X\cup B;Z_2)\to H^5(X,\partial X;Z_2)$, which should be easily computable.